# send a get request to url in monit (linux)

Tags: linux, monitoring, monit

I'm trying to find out when a file size increase stops and then sends a GET request to some URL.
already added this conf in

*/etc/monit/monitrc*

```
check file file.log with path /home/projects/my_project/file.log
    if timestamp > 15 minutes then alert
```

now I want to send a request to URL instead of *alert*.

something like this:

```
check file file.log with path /home/projects/my_project/file.log
    if timestamp > 15 minutes then request GET "http://my_url:8000"
```

Answer (score 1):

Monit can execute a script or command, instead of sending an alert only.

Use something like

> if timestamp > 15 minutes then exec /path/script.sh

See also https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html

A suggestion only.